# How to implement Meshlab's rotation manipulator?

Tags: mathematics, rotation, transformation

I want to implement a rotation handle/manipulator mechanism that would enable user to rotate a 3D model exactly like [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) does.

Unfortunately I don't fully understand how does the rotation gizmo work. In particular I don't understand how to make the model rotate only around the Z axis. Open Meshlab and try rotating *only* the blue circle to see what I mean. Rotations around the X and Y axis are easy to understand for me though.

How does one recreate the rotation mechanism of Meshlab, i.e. how *exactly* does horizontal and vertical panning translate to changes in angles?

[image: Meshlab rotation gizmo]

Comment: Assume your reader has never used meshlab, but is an expert in rotation math. You want that reader's help, right? Then include in your question a text description of the behaviour you want, and you make it that much easier for such experts to help you.

Comment: @DMGregoryI wish I could describe how does the handle work if I were able to comprehend it, but then I would not need to ask this question and could implement it by myself. Anyway, thankfully Meshlab is open-source and after digging through the code I was able to find [the relevant part of code](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib/blob/master/wrap/gui/trackmode.cpp#L68) that performs rotation. I found it's called arcball rotation.